# Center a button perfectly on the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been looking online and most people had an answer that deals with scaling yet I can't find that option. This is the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How do I make the button centered without any stretching (aka I want it to have it's content wrapped).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

An alternative approach is to use two nested LinearLayouts, one horizontal and one vertical. For instance:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The reason to do this is that a horizontal LinearLayout only pays attention to vertical `layout_gravity` values and a vertical LinearLayout only pays attention to horizontal `layout_gravity` values.

Comment: Welcome to the world of relative layouts I guess. I'll have to read up on the differences of them. Thanks for the quick response.